# Enviar string para planilha via email

Tags: javascript, script, google-sheets

Ola, eu tenho uma planilha no GoogleDocs, que envia, via script, um alerta via email para o usuario quando o prazo pra uma tarefa esta expirando. Eu gostaria que o usuario, ao receber essa mensagem, tenha a opção de clicar em um botão ou link para parar de receber, isto é, no caso de a tarefa ter sido cumprida.
Uma solução que estou pensando é, quando o usuário clicar no botão, a string "sim" seria enviada e substituiria o email do usuario. Assim, se o campo email tiver a string sim, ao inves do email, o script executaria, tentaria enviar o email, mas, como o registro não contem email valido, ele nao seria enviado. A planilha esta abaixo, e o codigo logo abaixo da planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function paraTest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows


  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
    var expire = dataRange[i][10]; 

    if (expire > 0 & expire < 10) {
      var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7];
      var subject = "Você tem um prazo de auditoria vencendo em " + dataRange[i][10] + " dias";
      //var teste = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][1], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var dataPreenchimento = new Date(dataRange[i][0]); //criei essas variaveis pq tava dando erro dataFormat, mas enviava normal.
      var dataFinal = new Date(dataRange[i][4]);

      var dataEnvio = Utilities.formatDate(dataPreenchimento, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var dataFim = Utilities.formatDate(dataFinal, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var message = "<P><r style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'> "
      + "*Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deve ser respondida até <font color=#FF0000;'>" + dataFim + "</r>" +
        "<P><a style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'>" 
      + "Identificação do Documento: </a>" + "<b style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'>" + dataRange[i][2] + "</b>" + "<P><b style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'> "
      + "Recomendação de Auditoria: </b> " + "<b style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'>" +  dataRange[i][3] + "</b>" + "<P><i style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'> OBS: Caso nao deseje mais receber avisos" +
        "(por exemplo, no caso de a recomendacao ja ter sido cumprida), remova seu email ou entre em contato</i></P>"
      +"<P><f style='color: #000000;'> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + 
        "---------------------------------------------------------------------</f></P>"+
          "<P><i style='color: #FF0000; font-size: 10px;'> NOTA: Amparada na Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, publicou um manual com novas regras de monitoramento." +
        "Para acessá-lo, consulte o manual de monitoramento, disponível <A href='url do manual'>aqui</A>. Contate pelos telefones: " +
          "33236780/6079 e e-mail: a@e.jus.br, para maiores informações </i></P>";

      + "<P><i style='color: #FF0000; font-size: 10px;'> NOTA: Amparada na Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, publicou um manual com novas regras de monitoramento." +
        "Para acessá-lo, consulte o manual de monitoramento, disponível <A href='url do manual'>aqui</A>. Contate pelos telefones: " +
          "33094780/6779 e e-mail: e@a.jus.br, para maiores informações </i></P>";

  //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});//da erro, porem, envia email normal. 
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress.toString(),
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message

      });
    } else if (expire < 0) {
      var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7];
      var dataPreenchimento = new Date(dataRange[i][0]); //criei essas variaveis pq tava dando erro dataFormat, mas enviava normal.
      var dataFinal = new Date(dataRange[i][4]);
      var dataEnvio = Utilities.formatDate(dataPreenchimento, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var dataFim = Utilities.formatDate(dataFinal, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var subject = "Você tem um prazo de auditoria que venceu em " + dataFim + "(" + dataRange[i][10] + " dias atras)";
      //var teste = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][1], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");

      var message = "<P><r style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'> "
      + "*Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento, de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deveria ter sido respondida até <font color=#FF0000;'>" + dataFim + "</r>" +
        "<P><a style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'>" 
      + "Identificação do Documento: </a>" + "<b style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'>" + dataRange[i][2] + "</b>" + "<P><b style='color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;'> "
      + "Recomendação de Auditoria: </b> " + "<b style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'>" +  dataRange[i][3] + "</b>" + "<P><i style='color: #000000; font-size: 11px;'> OBS: Caso nao deseje mais receber avisos" +
        "(por exemplo, no caso de a recomendacao ja ter sido cumprida), remova seu email ou entre em contato</i></P>"
      +"<P><f style='color: #000000;'> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + 
        "---------------------------------------------------------------------</f></P> " +
      "<P><i style='color: #FF0000; font-size: 10px;'> NOTA: Amparada na Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, publicou um manual com novas regras de monitoramento." +
        "Para acessá-lo, consulte o manual de monitoramento, disponível <A href='url do manual'>aqui</A>. Contate pelos telefones: " +
          "33626780/6779 e e-mail: e@a.jus.br, para maiores informações </i></P>";


  //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});//da erro, porem, envia email normal. 
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress.toString(),
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message

      });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Teria como você colocar o código do script? só com a imagem não da pra te ajudar.

Comment: Sim, ja editei com o codigo